# Integer sequence and RAM limits

Tags: prime-numbers, integer-sequence

I am trying to calculate the set of unique differences in a sequence, however the sequence grows fast and I hit the RAM limit of my PC for nthPrimeToUse = 11.  For nthPrimeToUse 1 to 10 the output of Length[abc4] is: 0,1,2,3,5,7,10,13,16,20,...  I am trying to find at least a few more terms if possible.  Here is the code:

Updated code: (outputs: 0,1,2,3,5,7,10,13,16,20 for nthPrimeToUse=1 to 10)

```
nthPrimeToUse = 5; 
primeNumber = Prime[nthPrimeToUse];
Primorial[n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]]
PrimorialToUse = Primorial[nthPrimeToUse - 1];
range = PrimorialToUse*primeNumber*2;
x = Select[(primeNumber) Range@range, GCD[#, PrimorialToUse ] == 1 &];
x = x/primeNumber;
valuesDivisibleByPrime = {}
For[i = 0, i < Length[x], i++,
 If[GCD[x[[i]], primeNumber] != 1,
  AppendTo[valuesDivisibleByPrime, x[[i]]]
  ]
 ]
x = Differences[valuesDivisibleByPrime] ;
CountDistinct[x]
```

This code is faster, possibly equivalent to the above code for nthPrimeToUse > 3
(outputs: 0,0,1,3,5,7,10,13,16,20 for nthPrimeToUse=1 to 10)

```
nthPrimeToUse = 5;
primeNumber = Prime[nthPrimeToUse];
Primorial[n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]]
PrimorialToUse = Primorial[nthPrimeToUse - 1];

coprimesOfPrimorial = 
  Select[Range[1, PrimorialToUse], CoprimeQ[PrimorialToUse, #] &];
abc1 = Length[coprimesOfPrimorial];
abc2 = Differences[coprimesOfPrimorial];
abc3 = CountDistinct[abc2];
abc4 = DeleteDuplicates[abc2];
abc4 = abc4*primeNumber;
Sort[abc4]
Length[abc4]
```

Thanks.

cheers,
Jamie

Comment: Maybe it's a known sequence? [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C5%2C7%2C10%2C13%2C16%2C20) has 7 suggestions.

Comment: Hi, none of them seemed likely to be the right sequence, but may need 3 terms to know.  I guess partitioning the sequence and then checking the partitions could save RAM.

Comment: Try asking on Math.SE for a closed form; it seems like there should be one.

Comment: Thanks, I asked the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284736/integer-sequence-possible-closed-form-solution

Comment: When I execute your code I get the sequence $\{0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13, 16,\ldots\}$. What are the correct values for $n=1,2,3$?

Comment: Hi, you caught an error I missed, I thought this code is equivalent to slower code, as it gave the same results for 5,7,10,13,16,20,..  however I didn't check it for the first four terms!  I believe the code will be equivalent for terms beyond 20, but can't be sure.  I will add the code that gives the 1,1,2,3,5,7,10,13,16,20 sequence to the post.